# Either in or of

Tags: prepositions

Is the usage of **in** in the following sentence wrong?

> The mission **in** his life is to improve the lot of the economically deprived and the socially oppressed.

I think it is correct. But according to my book it should be **of**.

Although **of** is correct but **in** is not incorrect.

Comment: HIs life's mission is etc.: that sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

Either way it isn't idiomatic. We usually say,

> A: *His mission in life is to . . .*

or

> B: *His life's mission is to . . .*

And if we are using A, we often preface it with *He sees*, and add *as*:

> He sees his mission in  life AS to . . .

HOWEVER . . .

As *His life's mission* is, logically, the same as *The mission of his life*, I suppose your book is correct, even though it's unidiomatic.